# Total CPU usage Object ID?

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, central-processing-unit, mib

How can i find the correct OID to get the total cpu usage of my Checkpoint (linux) based firewall? with 8 cores CPU.

I found this :

```
ssCpuUser .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9
ssCpuSystem .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.10
ssCpuIdle .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.11
```

But i want to the total CPU load in %

When i type TOP i can see this :

Cpu(s):  0.1%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  3.6%si,  0.0%st

So I tried the following calculation (100-ssCpuIdle) to get the percentage, but maybe there is an another solution?

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.11.0 | awk -F : '{print 100-$4}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.

This is the good checkpoint mib for cpu usage

procUsage 1.3.6.1.4.1.2620.1.6.7.2.4.0

You can find the mib here http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/vendor_index.cgi?r=checkpoint